# Method that extracts a list of URLs that match the pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Well, I'm trying to create a method, using Regex  , that will extract a list of URLs that matches this  pattern `@"http://(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.com"`, and so far I've done this :

```
public static List<string> Test(string url)
    {
        const string pattern = @"http://(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.com";
        List<string> res = new List<string>();

        MatchCollection myMatches = Regex.Matches(url, pattern);

        foreach (Match currentMatch in myMatches)
        {

        }

        return res;


    }
```

main issue is , which code should I use in foreach loop

```
        res.Add(currentMatch.Groups.ToString());
```

or

```
            res.Add(currentMatch.Value);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried either? Do they give you expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get all `.Match.Value`s. In your code, you should use

```
res.Add(currentMatch.Value);
```

Or, just use LINQ:

```
res = Regex.Matches(url, pattern).Cast<Match>()
           .Select(p => p.Value)
           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

`res.Add(currentMatch.Groups.ToString());` will give: `System.Text.RegularExpressions.GroupCollection` so you didn't test it.

---

How many matches do you expect from the parameter `url`?

I would use this:

```
static readonly Regex _domainMatcher =  new Regex(@"http://(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.com", RegexOptions.Compiled);

public static bool IsValidDomain(string url)
{
    return _domainMatcher.Match(url).Success;
}
```

or

```
public static string ExtractDomain(string url)
{ 
    var match = _domainMatcher.Match(url);
    if(match.Success)
        return match.Value;
    else
        return string.Empty;
}
```

Because the parameter is called `url` so it should be one `url`

---

If there are more possibilities and you want to extract all domainnames that matches the pattern:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ExtractDomains(string data)
{
    var result = new List<string>();

    var match = _domainMatcher.Match(data);

    while (match.Success)
    {
        result.Add(match.Value);

        match = match.NextMatch();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Notice the `IEnumerable<>` instead of `List<>` because there is no need to modify the result by the caller.

---

Or this lazy variant:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ExtractDomains(string data)
{
    var match = _domainMatcher.Match(data);

    while (match.Success)
    {
        yield return match.Value;
        match = match.NextMatch();
    }
}
```